# Reading a text document and converting it to a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error, traceback

I'm trying to make a basic script that reads a specified text document, asks for a string of characters to replace and what to replace it, then saves it:

```
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw()
    def OpenFile():
    fileName = askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users", filetypes = (("Text File", "*.txt"),("All Files","*.*")), title = "Open a document.")
    with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
        textFile = f.read()

OpenFile()
print(textFile)
```

There's an error when running the script and selecting a file

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\****\Documents\Python\Find and Replace\replace.py", line 11, in <module>
print(textFile)
NameError: name 'textFile' is not defined
```

Comment: Fix the indentation of your code please. It looks like you're defining the `textfile` variable inside your function. It's not going to be available outside it. Easiest fix is to just have your function return the resulting string.

Comment: Ok, I'm a little new to functions as I started learning python this week. I had no idea that variables didn't work outside them. Thanks!

Comment: variables do work outside them. It's just that variables you declare inside functions are local to the function.

Comment: Alright, I'll be sure to look further into functions so I don't make other mistakes like this.

Answer (score -2):

Game on: find what's different:

```
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw()

def OpenFile():
    fileName = askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users", filetypes = (("Text File", "*.txt"),("All Files","*.*")), title = "Open a document.")
    with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
        textFile = f.read()
        return textFile # RETURN THE FILE CONTENT HERE SO IT IS VISIBLE TO THE MAIN FUNCTION

textFile = OpenFile() # GET YOUR OUTPUT HERE SO YOU CAN PRINT IT ON THE NEXT LINE
print(textFile)
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained what you did to solve the problem before presenting the code. Otherwise, the reader is forced to go line-by-line and character-by-character to see what you did differently.

Comment: sure thanks. this is python 101 though, and just 10 lines of code. The OP might need to spend the time to figure what is different.

Comment: Remember that you're answering a question for someone that hasn't even made it through python 101 yet. They are an absolute beginner, and won't understand whether (or why) it's the `return` statement, the fact that you're saving the result to `textFile`, the fact that you changed the indentation for the `def`, or some combination.

Comment: stackoverflow shouldn't be a place where someone has to play a game to understand your answer. If you want to help, help. Don't throw up a roadblock to learning.

Comment: come on! s/he figured how to open a file, and read it: that's passed understanding function return statements. This is a basic error, and I am confident s/he will get that.

Comment: Exactly. You're feeding them an answer that they will cut and paste without thinking. And once they've done that, they still might not understand. Beginners really love to copy and paste code without understanding why it works. You have an opportunity to teach someone here, but instead you're providing them a solution they don't have to think about. Stackoverflow isn't just a place to help others, it can also be used as a place to improve your technical writing skills.

Comment: happy? Why don't you edit my answer if you don't like it.

Comment: The goal isn't to make me happy. The goal is to write a quality answer. Based on the votes, it seems at least a couple others agree that this is a low quality answer. I was just giving you advice on how I thought you could improve your answer. I've seen many, many answers on this site, and the best ones without exception include both an explanation and code. If you think this is the best answer you can write, it would be rude of me to rewrite it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This answer is only useful to this one person, the title has nothing to do with the problem. The issue has been answered 100's of times on SO. Nobody else will care. This question should have been closed. I was just trying to give this person a hint. Quality answers start with quality questions. We're not here to teach people python. The OP should get a book for that.

Comment: @MrE If the "answer is only useful to one person," then it shouldn't be answered -- Stack Overflow questions have to be useful to future readers.  If the question has "been answered 100's of times on SO," then it should be closed as a dupe instead of answered.

Comment: @NobodyNada agree, i should have. But i tend not to when it's a nube asking because it's very frustrating when you're askign your first question and people shut it down. So here we go, now we're having a meta debate on this stupid questions.